# Как с помощью aiogram отправить сообщение в канал Телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хотел написать бота благодаря aiogram, который сможет отправлять сообщения в канал Телеграм. Но появилась проблема, что я вовсе не знаю, как это сделать.

Немного кода, который есть сейчас:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def send_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(chat_id='example123', text = 'Привет!')
```

Я не понимаю как мне через message отправить сообщение.
Если у кого-то есть возможность отправьте пример кода, по отправке сообщение в Телеграм канал через aiogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример из документации.](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/broadcast_example.html)

```py
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, types

API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'
CHANNEL_ID = <CHANNEL ID HERE> # это должен быть int, например -1006666666666  

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)


async def send_message(channel_id: int, text: str):
    await bot.send_message(channel_id, text)


async def main():
    await send_message(CHANNEL_ID, '<b>Hello!</b>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Если попытаться вызвать функцию произойдёт ошибка ```name 'message' is not defined```, если не передавать этот параметр, при вызове функции произойдёт  другая ошибка, что тогда делать?

Comment: изменил код в ответе

Comment: `asyncio.run(main())`

Answer (score 0):

```
# импортируем нужные библиотеки
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types, Bot
from aiogram.utils import executor

# твой токен который ты получишь после создания бота у @BotFather
TOKEN = 'your_token'

# объекты бота
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot

# функция которая будет слать сообщение в твою группу
@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def main(message: types.Message):
    # строка, чтобы отправить что-нибудь в группу
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Hello World')

# запускаем бота
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

для того чтобы узнать id чата, введи код ниже в функцию выше вместо строки чтобы отправить что-нибудь в группу, id чата должен будет прийти тебе в лс

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id)
```