# Aiogram send message to telegram bot

Tags: python, aiogram

как отправит сообщение в телеграм бот через группу

Comment: Nurmuhammad Mamajonov, уточните пожалуйста, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Возможно, ваш ответ на вопрос находится здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249155/Как-с-помощью-aiogram-отправить-сообщение-в-канал-Телеграм